# Mocking of material-ui select component with jest

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs, react-testing-library

I created a React component which i'm trying to test with [React Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro). In my component i have following select component and its change handler

**Component.jsx**

```
<SingleSelect
  name="filter"
  label="Status"
  value={this.state.weatherStatus}
  options={this.state.weatherStatusOptions}
  onChange={this.handleFilterChange}
  testId="status"
/>
```

**onChange handleFilterChange function**

```
handleFilterChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({ weatherStatus: event.value });
}
```

An example of passing value `this.state.weatherStatus` is `{ id: 1, text: "cool weather"}`
For this I tried to write a mockup like below.

```
jest.mock('@material-ui/core/Select', () => props => (
  <div>
    <input
      onChange={(e) => props.onChange({ target: { value: e.target.value }})}
      value={props.value}
      data-testid={props['data-testid']}
    />
    {props.children}
  </div>
));

fireEvent.change(getByTestId('select'), { target: { value: { id: 1, text: "cool" } } });
expect(getByTestId('select').value).toEqual({ id: 1, text: "cool" });
```

But it is not working at all. any suggestion?

Comment: I'm pretty sure react-test-library doesn't work with Material-UI. I've been trying to get the fireEvents working for days and it just isn't happening.

Comment: Can you add some more data? What are you rendering in the tests? How does `SingleSelect` look like? What error do you get?

Answer (score 3):

it's definitely possible. I just managed to cracked it.

```js
jest.mock('@material-ui/core/Select', () => (...rest)=> {
   return(  
     <div>
       <input
         data-testid='mock-component'
       />
   </div>
   )
 });
```

You just need to put it above the describe.